# Увелечение суммы по количеству

Tags: javascript, jquery

При увеличении количества должа увеличиваться сумма, но при коливевстве 10, если нажать вниз, то сумма выводит 300, а должна вывести 100. Как это исправить?

```js
$("#kol").change(function() {
    nV = $(this).val();
    oV = this.name;
    this.name = nV;

    p = $(this).parent().parent();
    kol = $("#kol").val();
    showsum = $("#sum").val();
    sum = $("#realsum").val();

    if(nV > oV) {
        mul = parseInt(sum) + parseInt(showsum);
    } else {
        mul = parseInt(showsum) - parseInt(sum);
    }

    res = p.find("#sum");
    res.html(mul);
    total = 0;
    $("#sum").val(mul);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
Количевство: <input type="number" id="kol" min="5" value="5" step="5"><br><br>

Сумма:
<input type="hidden" id="realsum" value="100">
<input type="text" id="sum" min="100" value="100">
руб
```

Comment: Какой-то непонятный салат. `Количество` это кол-во купюр? Почему бы просто кол-во не умножать на 100?

Comment: 5шт стоит 100рублей.10шт стоит 200рублей. и.т.д идет

Comment: Сумма должна быть именно input или просто можно текстом вывести?

Comment: Если я количевство умножать на 100.То подумайте сами 1000шт стоит  50рублей.2000шт стоит 100рублей.1000*100?...

Comment: Можна проста текстом.

Comment: Количевство может менятся смотря на это и меняется сумма.То есть пример:15шт будет 5рублей.Если нажать верх то :30шт будет 10рублей и.т.д

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$('#num').change(function() {
  $('#sum').text(this.value * this.name / this.min);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

Количество <input id='num' type='number' value='10' min='10' step='10' name='100'>
<br>
Сумма: <span id='sum'>100</span>
```

Comment: Если честно, то с огромным трудом понимаю что нужно. Этот вариант подходит?

Comment: Я поменял `<input id='num' type='number' value='10' min='10' step='10'>` При увеличении поливество на `20` .Я получил `400 руб`.А должно` 10` штук стоит `100руб`.`20штук` стоит `200рублей`

Comment: @Sauron, пока вопрос не будет правильно сформулирован, я не смогу дать ответ. Если при 10шт нужно 100, а при 20 - 200, в чём проблема умножать на 10, вместо 20?

Comment: @Sauron, обновил ответ, может сейчас то что нужно? В `name` указывается минимальное значение суммы, а в `min` минимальное значение количества. При {5шт=100р, 10шт=200р}, При {15шт=100р, 30шт=200р}

Comment: Да вот теперь точно всё верно.Это и хотел получить).Спасибо еще раз

Comment: Еще одна проблема... Если сумма 22.20 руб при увеличении должна получить 44.40 руб а получает 44.4.

Comment: @Sauron, а разве 44.40 не равно 44.4? Это уже дело отображения, нужно искать как преобразовать десятичное число в строку с нулём в конце

Comment: @Sauron, `$('#sum').text((this.value * this.name / this.min).toFixed(2));` для нуля в конце. Но тогда и целое число будет с двумя нулями после точки